# Tensorflow: stacked bidirectional LSTMs

Tags: tensorflow

I want to stack two LSTMs without using `MultiRNN` wrapper. However, following code results with `ValueError: Shapes (3,) and (2,) are not compatible` because of `inputs=states_fw_1` in the second LSTM. How can I pass hidden state of the first LSTM as input to the second?

LSTM 1

```
    with tf.name_scope("BiLSTM_1"):
        with tf.variable_scope('forward_1'):
            cell_fw_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)

        with tf.variable_scope('backward_srl'):
            cell_bw_srl = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)

        outputs_1, states_1 = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
            cell_fw=cell_fw_1,
            cell_bw=cell_bw_1,
            dtype=tf.float64,
            sequence_length=self.input_seq_len,
            inputs=self.embedded_input_layer,
            scope='BiLSTM_1')
```

State is tuple

```
    states_fw_1, states_bw_1 = states
```

LSTM 2

```
    with tf.name_scope("BiLSTM_2"):
        with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
            cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)

        with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
            cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)

        outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
            cell_fw=cell_fw,
            cell_bw=cell_bw,
            dtype=tf.float64,
            sequence_length=self.input_seq_len,
            inputs=states_fw_1,
            scope="BiLSTM_extraction")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning TF 2 days (so I'm not pro-guy) and I found this problem to be interested to resolve.

Here are my findings:
You want to do thing which is not possible to obtain using 'LSTMCell' implementation. Here is why:

1. You want to feed the "states_fw_1 to the next BI-LSTM. So, first question should be: What are dimensions of "states_fw_1"? For any RNN implementation you need [batch_size, seq_len, input_size]. For  "states_fw_1" it is [batch_size, hidden_size] (I have just check the size of "states_fw_1" running below code). So you can see that your output does not fit to RNN requirements. It is because model output just one the last state of LSTM cell, not all the history (see the [documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard8/tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn.md)). And you are not interested in last state, because you want feed state[t-step] to the layer above.The 'state_fw_1' is useful when you want to classify the sequence (not each element in sequence)
   Edit: 'state_fw_1' contain the last "hidden_state" and last "memory_cell". For classification only "hidden_state" will be usefull, I think.
2. So you just need to use the merged output (from forward and backward pass) . And 'LSTMCell' cell output have size [batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size*2], (*2 as forward and backward) so it is right for next stacked RNN (output come from each time-step, not like the state).

Here is the code which I was testing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

hidden_size = 21
seq_len = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, 32])
with tf.variable_scope('BiLSTM_1'):
  with tf.variable_scope('forward_1'):
    cell_fw_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
  with tf.variable_scope('backward_srl'):
      cell_bw_1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
  outputs_1, states_1 = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
      cell_fw=cell_fw_1,
      cell_bw=cell_bw_1,
      dtype=tf.float32,
      sequence_length=seq_len,
      inputs=inputs,
      scope='BiLSTM_1')

# Merge Output tensor from forward and backward pass. It size is [batch_size, seq_len, 2*hidden_size]
outputs_1 = tf.concat(outputs_1, 2)

with tf.name_scope("BiLSTM_2"):
  with tf.variable_scope('forward'):
      cell_fw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
  with tf.variable_scope('backward'):
      cell_bw = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)
  outputs, states = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
      cell_fw=cell_fw,
      cell_bw=cell_bw,
      dtype=tf.float32,
      sequence_length=seq_len,
      inputs=outputs_1,
      scope="BiLSTM_2")

# Initializate the weights and biases
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
batch_size = 5
seq_len_val = 10
train_inputs = np.zeros((batch_size, seq_len_val, 32))
train_seq_len = np.ones(batch_size) * seq_len_val
with tf.Session() as session:
  session.run(init)
  feed = {inputs: train_inputs, seq_len: train_seq_len}
  out,state,state_1 = session.run([outputs,states, states_1],feed)

print ("State size: ", state_1[0].c.shape, " Out Size: ", out[0][0].shape)
print ("Batch_size: ", batch_size, " Sequence Len: ", seq_len_val, " Hidden Size: ", hidden_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

'outputs_1' returned by LSTM 1 is a tuple containing 'outputs_fw' and 'outputs_bw'.

'outputs_fw' and 'outputs_bw' will be of dimension: [batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size].

You have to concatenate 'outputs_fw' and 'outputs_bw' hidden states (us tf.concat with axis=2) and pass that as input to LSTM 2 instead of passing 'states_fw_1' as input to LSTM 2.